# How to get projection, rotation and translation matrix from ARKit?

Tags: ios, arkit

Hi I need to take a set of photos with my iphone and read the corresponding projection matrix, rotation and translation matrix for post-processing. I have never used ARKit or programmed in Swift/Object C before. What is the best way to get started?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a default AR project in Xcode then you'll be able to study the basics of getting an AR app running in Swift.

To read the camera parameters you need to implement this function:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    guard let transform = frame.camera.transform else {return}
    let position = SCNVector3Make(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z)

    let rotation = frame.camera.eulerAngles
    let projection = frame.camera.projectionMatrix

    print(position)
    print(rotation)
    print(projectionMatrix)
    print("================="
}
```

(I.e copy / paste that code as another function in your `ViewController` class in the default app. The rotation is given in euler angles.

Given you've not used Swift before this may not be that helpful. But in theory it's all you need.

ARKit grabs frames at 60 frames per second (you can change this) - this function is called automatically for every new frame.

If you're using it to take photos you'll have to add more code to get all the timing right etc.